# Blender 2d animation, Draw lines in draw mode but cannot erase them, cannot edit them

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d, layers

working in 2d animation I got stuck. I could draw fine, and I could select grease pencil objects and go to all the modes, but all modes apart from draw mode seems stuck. I could not select or edit some strokes in edit mode. The same strokes seemed locked in sculpt mode. And in draw mode I could not erase them. But this was only with some strokes not all. It seemed to have no link to the layers or anything I could find. and some of the strokes that I could not edit, where highlighted as though I had selected them, but I could not deselect them.

I have been stuck on this all day but asking so I can going to reply to myself as solved it. But could not find anything on the internet about this. So hoping this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that in Blender 2d animation. locking a material from being edited also lockes any strokes from being selected and moved if they have this material.
This is really confusing Grease pencil feature, it made me asume I had the layer locked even though it seemed like it was unlocked, or I had the stroke on the wrong layer. Spent the last 2 hours troubleshooting it and trying to recreate it.

It means you can draw lines in draw mode but cannot erase them, cannot edit them.

Locking materials seems like it should just stop the material from being edited but it locks what it has been applied to as well.

Anyway just posting as I spent so long googling and could not find the solution. was about to admit defeat and delete my project and start again, assuming it was strange bug. hopefully a google search with bring this up for the next person who gets this issue